# Activerecord query to SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to know if there is a way to obtain the SQL query from an ActiveRecord query without actually performing the query. I am looking for something like this:

```
get_sql_query(Item.where(status: 'open')) 
# SELECT * FROM items WHERE status="open"
```

Comment: So what you want is a conversion from ActiveRecord to SQL?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `to_sql` method like this:

```
User.where(name: 'Oscar').to_sql
# returns SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."name" = 'Oscar'
```

In your case, it would be:

```
Item.where(status: 'open').to_sql
```